# Need information on ethernet bootloader for AT32UC3A0512

Tags: debugging, ethernet, bootloader, atmel

I am planning to develop ethernet bootloader. So I wanted to modify the existing DFU Bootloader program. I want to delete the already existing bootloader on micro-controller flash and put my own bootloader.

Currently my MCU is AT32UC3A0512. I am using AVR Dragon and AVR One debugger/programmer. Is it possible to reprogram the bootloader region with AVR Dragon or AVR One? or I must need to have MKII debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to reprogram the boot loader with AVR One and I would guess that
the AVR Dragon works too (if you can use it to program the AVR32s generally).
The boot loader (if present) resides in the beginning of internal flash and is written as any other bit of code.